# Как прочитать файл со страницы с автозагрузкой этого файла?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

У меня есть ссылка на xls файл, при открытии файл автоматически загружается и вкладка с ссылкой закрывается.Но как мне заставить программу прочесть этот файл имея ссылку? Просто файл часто обновляется и хочется, чтобы программа самый свежий файл обрабатывала.
Пробовал urllib, выдает длинную последовательность символов, из которой не мог вынуть хоть что-то.Вот рандомный отрезок:'\xde\x00\x02\x00\x19\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\xfd\x00\n\x00\xdf\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\xb8\x01\x00\x00\xfd\x00\n\x00\xdf\x00\x01\x00\x1a\x00\xb9\x01\x00\x00\xfd\x00\n\x00\xdf\x00\x02\x00\x19\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\xd7\x00\xc6\x00\xc0\x07\x00\x00l\x02\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00\x0e\x00'
Пробовал прогонять через онлайн декодеры всякие.С таблицами, информация которых вбита в код страницы это срабатывало.Пробовал декодить использу кодировки UTF-8, ascii, но результата не принесло: 'codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 0'

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, желаемые результат. Так будет гораздо легче ответить на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: В том и дело, что результат неизвестен.Я никак не могу вынуть понятную информацию с кода страницы ссылки, в этом и вопрос.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889

Comment: Если вы не знаете, какой должен быть результат, то почему вы решили, что этот результат некорректный? Уверен, это вполне корректный кусок вполне корректного xls-файла, который вы зачем-то выдрали без попытки корректно распарсить.

Comment: Я для открытия файлов excel пользуюсь библиотекой `openpyxl`, скорее всего, файл корректен, как Вам сказали выше. Его просто нужно правильно обработать.